# how to get the null values named as some string after performing rolup

Tags: sql

how to get the null values named as some string  after performing rolup

Comment: When you don't even bother to explain your own problem properly why should we bother to help you. If you want some help then add more information on the query you are using, add sample data, current result and expected result

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "NULL in Result Sets" section in the below link: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx

Actually I assumed you want to rather replace the nulls with a string rather than renaming the column...
Even if replacing, there is a difference in imputing original null values vs. the rolled up totals being displayed with null values.

Comment: Yeah that's my question and thanks for being so understanding.